# Missing required parameters for [Route: user.profile]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I am trying to create user profile in my laravel app where every user can view every user's profile and I got an error

> **Missing required parameters for [Route: user.profile]**

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Here is my code:

**web.php**

`Route::get('user/profile/{id}', 'UserProfileController@profile')->name('user.profile');`

**Controller(UserProfileController)**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\User; 

class UserProfileController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => [ 'profile']]);
    }
    public function profile($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);
        return view('user.profile', compact('user') );
    }

}
```

**View(profile.blade.php)**

```
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ $user->name }}'s Profile page</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    Hi, {{ $user->name }} This is a private profile page!!!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: I think the issue is on `app.blade.php`, not in the code here. It's trying to create the route but it's not passing in the `$id`. Can you show the relevant part of `app.blade.php`?

Comment: your problem in `app.blade.php`, or u can remove from `profile.blade.php` `@extends('app.blade.php')` )

Comment: That is correct!! ```<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('user.profile') }}">
                                        <i class="fas fa-user"></i>    Profile
                                    </a>``` 

How do I pass id?

Answer (score 1):

if you read your error attentively the error says about app.blade.php , so go to the app.blade.php and look for the error.
probably you should be looking to **

> anchor tag pass the id to it

**

and to add further for newer version of laravel you could use model binding to reduce the code

> public function profile(User $user)

{

> ```
>            return view('user.profile')->withUser($user);
> }
> ```

Comment: I did this but I got the error
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{route('user.profile', $id)}}">
                                        <i class="fas fa-user"></i>    Profile
                                    </a>

Comment: $user->id should be there

Comment: `<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{route('user.profile',$user->$id)}}"> <i class="fas fa-user"></i>    Profile </a>`

Undefined variable: user (View: /home/riwaj/Desktop/dmt-intern-manager/InternManager/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php)

Comment: return view('user.profile')->with('user',$user); try once or dd($user) in controller to check once

Comment: return the vide didn't work. can you please clarify on dd($user)

Comment: may be your app blade doesnot know about user variable you might define it while extending but i am not sure ::: @extends('master', ['title' => $title]) ==> in your case
@extends('app', ['user' => $user])

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your `layouts/app.blade.php`
You have forgotten the required 'id' parameter.
Use `{{route('user.profile', $id)}}`